# How to check if multiple children have the same child under them

Tags: android, firebase

Not sure exactly how to word this question, but I'm trying to make a function that will look at a database and see if two or more users have liked the same thing then start a chat between them.  The problem I'm running into is the second if always seems to evaluate to false even though the two Log lines show the variables to have the correct values.  If more context or explanation is needed, just let me know.  Any help is greatly appreciated, I've been beating my head on this one way too long.

````
private void isLikeMatch(String likeId, String groupId) {
        DatabaseReference currentGroupConnectionsDb = groupsDb.child(groupId).child("users");
        currentGroupConnectionsDb.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onChildAdded(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot, @Nullable String previousChildName) {
                if (snapshot.exists()){
                    String user = snapshot.getKey();
                    Log.d("user", user);
                    Log.d("Item", likeId);
                    if (snapshot.child(user).child("connections").child("yep").child(likeId).exists()){
                        Log.d("here?", "It saw a connection");
                        String key = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Chat").push().getKey();
                        groupsDb.child("matches").child(likeId).child(user).child("ChatId").setValue(key);
                        //usersDb.child(currentUId).child("connections").child("matches").child(snapshot.getKey()).child("ChatId").setValue(key);
                    }
                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildChanged(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot, @Nullable String previousChildName) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildRemoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildMoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot, @Nullable String previousChildName) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

            }
        });
    }```
````

Answer (score 0):

This ended up being a logic error more than anything.  Changed the childevenlistener to a singlevalueeventlistener and set it to look for a more specific variable inside the database.  It now works like a charm.

Comment: Please add a tags on your post to be more accessible and understandable